# Check if subprocess.getoutput command executed successfully

Tags: python

I have a java program that I have to run from python, get the output and store the result in 3 variables (if it works as expected, should print 3 values, each one on a different line).

This is the code that I'm using:

```
stdout1 = subprocess.getoutput("java -jar test.jar" + " -r " + path1)
x, y, z = stdout1.splitlines()[:]
```

If the path1 is not found by the test.jar program it will output a message to check the path.

Is there a way to check if the program executed correctly, and only then store the output?

```
x, y, z = stdout1.splitlines()[:]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
import subprocess

try:
    stdout1 = subprocess.check_output("java -jar test.jar" + " -r " + path1, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    # handle error
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: Thank you! Is there an equivalent for python 3.x? I get an error here except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e: invalid syntax.

Comment: This works in python3, maybe you have the wrong indent or something

Comment: The error came from Atom python 3 kernel. I've tested it in jupyter notebook and works as expected. Thank you!

Comment: @AMayer Interesting, it's standard Python3 error syntax https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html So i'm not sure what would be wrong, must be something else

Comment: It is buggy, I commented a line, saved the file and run Atom just like jupyter with shift+enter each line to see the output and it tries to run the commented line and still prints an error except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e: invalid syntax. But the same code works as expected if i run it from terminal or jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the returned code of the subprocess explicitly:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

process = run('java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar test.jar'.split()
              + ['-r', path], stdout=PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
if process.returncode == 0:  # success
    x, y, z = process.stdout.splitlines()
```

Note: this code runs `java` executable without starting a new shell.

The code uses the explicit utf-8 encoding to avoid depending on the default locale encoding that might not support all necessary characters.

---

A minimal code change in your case would be to replace `getoutput()` with `getstatusoutput()` which returns `(exitcode, output)` tuple and check whether `exitcode` is zero to determine success.

`getstatusoutput()` starts a new shell    even if it is unnecessary and therefore it is not recommended. Also, passing `path` unescaped opens you to the shell command injection vulnerability if you start the shell.

`getstatusoutput()` calls `check_output()` internally and catches the exception (it is equivalent to the previous answer).

Comment: Thank you!. It works perfectly on my workstation. Will it work on python 2.7 as well? I have to provide this code and I cannot assume that everyone uses python 3.x. from subprocess import run, PIPE
ImportError: cannot import name run.

Comment: @AMayer yes, run() can be implemented on Python 2.7 too (in terms of Popen.communicate()). Though, Python 2.7 won't be maintained past 2020. I wouldn't start *new* project in Python 2.

Comment: I understand. Am I missing something then here?  from subprocess import run, PIPE ImportError: cannot import name run. I just installed python 2.7 to test it and got that error.

Comment: @AMayer: I can only repeat my previous comment. For clarity, there is no `subprocess.run` on Python 2.7 as well as there is no `subprocess.getoutput()`. One can define them using existing `subprocess.Popen` class and its method `.communicate()`.